# Cannot extract mozilla-central mercurial bundle

Tags: firefox, mercurial

I am trying to set up the repository for Mozilla Firefox on my PC. I have installed the tools required and am stuck at setting up the mercurial repository on my local PC. [Mercurial Bundles - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Source_Code/Mercurial/Bundles) is what i am following. As I have a slow internet connection, I decided to download the .bz2 file from [here](https://hg.mozilla.org). I initiated the repo using the `hg init` command but i am unable to unbundle the .bz2 file. Here is the command

`hg unbundle mozilla-central-35b211eaad1f.tar.bz2` but the console gives me the following error : `abort: mozilla-central-35b211eaad1f.tar.bz2: not a Mercurial bundle`. I also tried `hg unbundle mozilla-central-35b211eaad1f.tar`. But it still shows me the same error.

Also let me know if I am posting this question in the wrong place.

Comment: It looks like you downloaded a checkout (as evidenced by the `.tar.bzr` extension and you using hg.mozilla.org. Bundles are available from [hg.cdn.mozilla.net](https://hg.cdn.mozilla.net/).